# Routing between 2 Networks [Gateway is on a different Network]

Tags: networking, router, routing

due to a hardware failure I have to put a temp. solution in place to give internet to a small office.

We have the office network like this: 192.168.1.0/24 with a Windows DC at 192.168.1.5.
The only working internet router now is the one used for our phone connections (the main internet router went bye bye on us).

The network where we still have internet is 192.168.0.0/24 with the router at 192.168.0.1.

I have done the following so far:

- disabled DHCP on the "phone" router
- connected the phone router to our main network switch
- connected the dc on it's second NIC to the main network switch with an IP of 192.168.0.10 and gateway of 192.168.0.1 (IP of the "phone" router)
- added a route on the "phone" router to network 192.168.1.0/24 with gateway 192.168.0.10

The Domain Controller now has internet which is good. But how do I get all other PC's to use the available internet connection?

Do I have to setup routes on every single PC or can I (I would prefer it this way of cource) do something on the DC that routes all traffic to the temporary gateway?

I thought of setting the DC (192.168.1.5) as the the gateway on all PC's (through it's DHCP) and since the DC knows that the way to the internet is 192.168.0.1 but that somehow that doesn't work.

regards

Comment: You want the DC to act as a router. Is it configured for that?

Comment: no because it did not have to route untill now, How do I configure it to do so?

Comment: You're going to need your "phone" router to do NAT for the other subnet as well. If it can handle a second NAT range, you can set it up that way. Or if it can handle a /23 subnet mask (255.255.25**4**.0) for the NAT private subnet, you can do that (192.168.0.0/23 covers both subnets). If it can't do either, you may need to make your DC box act as a NAT gateway for the subnet behind it.

Comment: So doing the nat (which should be possible) does the trick? Do I need any additional routes or change something else for it to work? What gateway would I now set on all clients?

Comment: I installed the Routing & RAS role and it works like a treat. Enabeling NAT was the puzzle piece that was missing. Thanks a lot @Spiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Spiff I was able to get it up and running.
I installed the Routing & RAS role on my Windows Server.
Inside the configuration under IPv4 -> NAT I selected my internet connected NIC and went into the settings and checked the box to activate NAT on this interface.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).